# Control Chromecast Audio volume using Chrome API

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I need to draw in UI a proper volume level on client (sender) side when working with Chromecast Audio. I see there are two ways of receiving (and might setting as well) volume from Chromecast - from `Receiver` and `Media` namespaces. In my understanding `Receiver` namespace stores general device's volume while `Media` namespace stores volume of currently played track.

1. It seems that I can't receive media volume by using `GET_STATUS` request for `Media` namespace before I load any tracks with `LOAD` request. Then how do I correctly display volume that will be used before loading media? Changing in UI `RECEIVER` volume to `MEDIA` volume after media is loaded doesn't look like a good solution and will be a surprise for users.
2. I fail to control volume using `SET_VOLUME` request for `Receiver` namespace - I've got no reply from Chromecast

   ```
   Json::Value msg, response;
   msg["type"] = "SET_VOLUME";
   msg["requestId"] = ++request_id;
   msg["volume"]["level"] = value; // float
   response = send("urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.receiver", msg);
   ```

   If the following lines are used instead of the last one, media volume is controlled OK:

   ```
   msg["mediaSessionId"] = m_media_session_id;
   response = send("urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media", msg);
   ```

   What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the volume on the receiver, you should be using the SDK's APIs instead of sending a hand-crafted message. For example, you should use [setReceiverVolumeLevel()](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.Session#setReceiverVolumeLevel). Also, use the receiver volume and not the stream volume.

Comment: I'd be glad to use it if SDK's API covered all platforms, languages and use cases. But as I'm developing neither Android, iOS not Chrome app, I can't use that.

Comment: @plátanoplomo I'm working on an Android native C++ app. It's going to be ported to other platforms.